# Getting HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException when using spring security formLogin

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to build a web app for a local supermarket using Angular 16 for the frontend and Spring boot (3.1.3) for the backend.

In angular, this is how I'm submitting my form:

```
login() {
    console.log(this.loginFormGroup.value);
    this.loginFormGroup.markAllAsTouched();
    if (this.loginFormGroup.valid) {
      this.loginSubscription = this.userService.login({
        username: this.loginFormGroup.controls["username"].value,
        password: this.loginFormGroup.controls["password"].value,
        rememberMe: this.loginFormGroup.controls["rememberMe"].value as string,
      }).subscribe({
        next: (response: Response) => {
          if (response.errorCode === "5") {
            // this.router.navigateByUrl("/home").catch((error) => {
            //   console.error('Navigation failed!', error);
            // });
            console.log("testing");
          }
          else {
            alert(response.body.message);
          }
        },
        error: (error) => {
          alert(error);
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log(this.loginFormGroup.errors);
    }
  }
```

UserService service:

```
public login(loginInfo: any): Observable<Response> {
    const url: string = environment.apiUrl + "user/login";
    return this.http.post<Response>(url, JSON.stringify(loginInfo));
  }
```

(where `environment.apiUrl` is equal to `"http://localhost:8080/"`)

In spring boot, I have the following security configuration where some requests are allowed to certain endpoints, some are allowed if the user is a `CUSTOMER` or `ADMIN` roles, and some are allowed if the user is an `ADMIN`:

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity.cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/product/**", "/auth/**", "/user/**")
                        .permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/hello") //for testing purposes
                        .hasAnyRole(Role.ADMIN.name(), Role.CUSTOMER.name())
                        .requestMatchers("/helloAdmin") //for testing purposes
                        .hasRole(Role.ADMIN.name())
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated())
                .formLogin(httpSecurityFormLoginConfigurer -> httpSecurityFormLoginConfigurer.loginProcessingUrl("/user/login"))
                .logout(httpSecurityLogoutConfigurer -> httpSecurityLogoutConfigurer.logoutUrl("/user/logout").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID"))
                .rememberMe(httpSecurityRememberMeConfigurer -> httpSecurityRememberMeConfigurer.rememberMeParameter("rememberMe").key("some key"))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .exceptionHandling(exc -> exc.authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) ->
                        restExceptionHandler.handleUnauthenticatedUser(request, response)))
                .build();
    }
```

In the `handleUnauthenticatedUser`, I send a custom response.

Here's my login endpoint (for testing purposes of course):

```
@PostMapping("/user/login")
    public Response login(@RequestBody HashMap<String, String> request, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
        HashMap<String, String> body = new HashMap<>();
        body.put("message", "User logged in successfully");
        return new Response("5", body);
    }
```

Each time a request is made from angular, I get this exception `HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException`. I tried changing the login endpoint from `@PostMapping` to `@GetMapping` and it works just fine (and in angular too). However, it's not best to send user information in a get request. And I also want to know why I am getting this exception? I searched for tutorials for spring security form login, and they were all the same and they used POST.

I tried messing with the `httpSecurityFormLoginConfigurer` a bit, but to no avail (loginPage, successHandler...).

It's also worth noting that in the network tab, there are two requests (when I'm using POST):

1. Request URL: http://localhost:8080/user/login
   Request Method: POST
   Status Code: 302 Found
2. Request URL: http://localhost:8080/login?error
   Request Method: GET
   Status Code: 200 OK which includes a custom response (no mapping for this request)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks a lot :)

Comment: To login you have to call `/login` instead of `"user/login"`. If you call `"user/login"` you are not logged in and redirected to your login page.

Comment: @dur i tried using `/login` instead of `/user/login`, but I'm still getting the same error. I tried `login` instead of `/login` and it worked. So I changed '/user/login' to `user/login` and it also worked. Can you please elaborate? Tutorials I have seen used `/something`

Comment: @dur also should I update any of my existing urls in the security configuration?